# j2me record and stream without gap?

Tags: audio, java-me, nokia, record, series-40

Is it possible to record voice and stream in J2ME,like I record and use `commit()` to get the byte array,but the `commit()` takes at least 250ms ,even the record length is 10 ms,and it irrationally takes 280ms if the record length is 10s etc, 
the device I tested is Nokia 6300 s40 device.
How can I prevent the gap?
Actually I need to record voice in a packets of the time intervals as small as possible like 100ms,200ms,etc. but each time the `commit()` takes at least 250ms.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its not possible. Because you have to `commit()` after recording the audio. So it should takes sometime to `commit()`.